# Whats causing Drupal to freeze when creating/editing a mini-panel?

Tags: javascript, panels, performance

I'm quite new to drupal.

Drupal has been freezing for me when I try and create or sometimes edit a minipanel. Once I select the panel layout and start adding content it just remains in the lightbox 'grayed' state and wont let me click or do anything. It's almost like it's trying to load but I've left it for an hour and it's completely frozen.

I've tried on Firefox and IE10 and get same issue. Also upgraded my drupal from 7.23 to 7.24 today so a completely new core is running but still hangs like this.

I haven't fully explored everything yet in drupal so I don't know if other sections will do this. So far it's just the minipanels section.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the description of your problem, it seems to being caused by a Javascript error.

Try to check with [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or the debug tool of your preference on the browser, go to "Console" tab and look for Javascripts errors or maybe on the "Network" panel to check for XHR (ajax) problems.

Comment: Console reports nothing. But in Network XHR I get a time latency of 16036.1 days on:

http://localhost/drupal/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js?v=1.8.11&_=1385699457134

http://localhost/drupal/misc/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.2.1&_=1385699457165

http://localhost/drupal/modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js?v=1.0&_=1385699457212

Comment: I think that you are using the jQuery update module and the version set is 1.8, sometimes that version is incompatible with other contrib modules.
To confirm this, go to admin/config/development/jquery_update and switch the  jQuery version to 1.7, and then look if the problem persists.

Comment: Wow, you nailed it. Thanks so much for helping. PS. How the heck did you know that?

Comment: Thanks, I had similar problems but with other contrib modules. I found out that, most of the times, this problem is caused because many contrib modules were developed using jQuery 1.7 and the 1.8 version has some changes that are slightly incompatible.

Tip: If you chose to use the 1.7, make sure that all your development is compatible with that jQuery version.